# Solving a system of differential equations involving trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

While working on a math problem involving Euler angles, the following nonlinear system of equations arises:
\begin{align}
\dot{\psi} &= a \cos\psi \sin(\phi+\delta)  +  \sin\phi \csc\theta  \newline
\dot{\theta} &= a \cos\psi\sin\theta \cos(\phi+\delta) + \cos\phi  \newline
\dot{\phi} &=  a\sin\psi \cos(\phi+\delta) - \sin\phi\cot\theta 
\end{align}
where $a$ and $\delta$ are known real number. 
Dot means a derivative with respect to $t$, i.e. $\dot{f} = \mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}t$.
The system is subject to the initial conditions $\psi(t=0)=0, \theta(t=0)=\pi/2$, and $\phi(t=0) = 0$.

In the particular situation of $a=0$, the system can straightforwardly be solved. 
i was wondering whether a general solution can also be obtained when $a \ne 0$.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated -- thank you.